# Why does my linear mixed model not output the random slopes for the model?

Tags: mixed-model, python, categorical-data, statsmodels

I have this dataframe:

| subject | delta | day_of_week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30 | 0 |
| C | -20 | 3 |
| Y | -2 | 0 |
| S | 10 | 4 |
| A | -5 | 1 |

And I am trying to train a linear mixed model using the statsmodel library with this code:

```
lmm = smf.mixedlm(
        "delta ~ subject", 
        metricsDf, 
        groups=metricsDf["day_of_week"], 
        re_formula="~subject"
      ).fit()

re = lmm.random_effects
print(re)
```

but when I look at the random effects parameters this is the output:

```
{
 0: 
    Group   -0.299498
    dtype: float64, 
 1: Group    1.679702
    dtype: float64, 
 2: Group   -1.500649
    dtype: float64, 
 3: Group   -0.789772
    dtype: float64, 
 4: Group    0.962137
    dtype: float64, 
 6: Group   -0.05192
    dtype: float64
}
```

But I was expecting there to be random intercepts and random slopes included, not just random intercepts.

My guess is that it has to do with "subject" being a categorical variable but I am having a hard time finding useful information for this library. The docs have not helped me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `re_formula = 1 + x` where x is the variable having a random slope.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, it still outputs only the intercept random factor.

Comment: Please copy your complete code (or update it above) and I will comment further.

Comment: I added the code used to return the random_effect parameters in the original post but I am not sure if that is helpful. Not sure what else I can add that would be useful, please let me know if there is anything specific that would help answer the question. @KerbyShedden

Comment: I think you probably want the mean structure formula to be `delta ~ day_of_week`, `groups="subject"` and `re_formula="1+day_of_week"`.

Comment: `groups` should be a variable that partitions the observations into blocks such that there are correlations within but not between blocks.  In a study with repeated measures on human subjects, usually the groups variable should be the subject identifier.